# Getting this error : Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid envelope - While adding the contact

Tags: flutter

I am getting the error while adding the contact using contact service.

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();

newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
newContact.familyName ="abc";

newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
```

Comment: Can you specify the error you receive?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid envelope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this solve your problem

```
 PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
    .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.contacts);

if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
  await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.contacts]);
  PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
      .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.contacts);

  if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
   Contact newContact = new Contact();

     newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
     newContact.familyName ="abc";

      newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

     await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
  } else {
    //_handleInvalidPermissions(context);
  }
} else {
   Contact newContact = new Contact();

     newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
     newContact.familyName ="abc";

      newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

     await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will solve your problem:

The latest version for handling permissions is now

`permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1`

```
    Future<void> saveContactInPhone() async {
    try {

      print("saving Contact");
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await Permission.contacts.request();
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

      if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      Contact newContact = new Contact();

        newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
        newContact.familyName ="abc";

          newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

        await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);

      } else {
        //_handleInvalidPermissions(context);
      }
    } else {
      Contact newContact = new Contact();

        newContact.givenName ="Ajay";
        newContact.familyName ="abc";

          newContact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile",value: "9998887771")];

        await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
    }
      print("object");      

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `PermissionHandler` already, and you are still getting this error, make sure that you declare that your app uses permission for **writing contacts** in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.app">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> <!-- this one! -->

  other stuff....
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my contact save code which works in both Android and iOS, please try in your,

```
    Contact newContact = new Contact();
    newContact.givenName = NAME; //NAME = desire name
    newContact.emails = [Item(label: "email", value: EMAIL)]; //EMAIL = desire email
    newContact.phones = [Item(label: "phone", value: PHONE)]; //PHONE = desire phone
    newContact.company = COMPANY; //COMPANY = desire company name
    newContact.jobTitle = JOB_TITLE; //JOB_TITLE = desire job title
    await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Can you please tell me the YAML file dependency ? I am using  contacts_service: ^0.3.0

Comment: contacts_service: only no version added

Comment: Have you added permission in AndroidMenifest.xml for contacts?

Comment: Yes Added. Not not getting the error but contacts not storing

Comment: Can you please share a good example or link for taking the permission while adding the contact ?

Comment: I just follow instructions given in dart lib for contact and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For solving this problem you should apply permissions on write data in contacts. It's a dangerous permissions, so add permission only in manifest is not enough. 
For call window applying or denying permissions you can use `permission_handler 4.2.0` .

```
await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.contacts]);
```

After calling this method you can apply permission and contact will be added.
By the way, this solution is needed only for android devices with Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher. In lower versions you apply all permissions, when install your app.